# How to execute Vim commands in a file, like .vimrc?

Tags: file, list, vi, vim

I need to create a file with a list of commands (in particular key mappings) that I *may* sometimes need, like a .vimrc that I can execute inside Vim when I need them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try [`:source file`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:source)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that it was so simple and I was so much time not being able to find it. Thanks!